# C - Order of Evaluation for equation

Tags: c, equation, operator-precedence

I have done a ton of research as to how the order of evaluation goes - but cannot figure out how it would go for this equation:

```
z = !x + y * z / 4 % 2 - 1
```

My best guess is (from left to right):

```
z = !x + {[([y * z] / 4) % 2] - 1}
```

Comment: Do you understand how to interpret the precedence table at e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_operator_precedence#Operator_precedence?

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/operator.7.html

Comment: Did your "ton of research" include the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/), particularly section 3?

Comment: I should mention that in C terminology, that's not an "equation"; it's an "expression", specifically an assignment expression. A mathematical equation asserts that the LHS and RHS are equal; an assignment evaluates the RHS and stores the resulting value in the object designated by the LHS. They both use the same `=` symbol, but they're very different things.

Comment: Order of evaluation is not same as precedence. The precedence matters when we have multiple operators. This implies one operator will have a higher priority over the other. Evaluation implies simplification of the OPERANDS when an operator is applied to the operands (Eg; a * b). Here a and b can be further complex parameters. So we do not know whether b would be evaluated before than a or vice versa.

Answer (score 7):

Order of evaluation and operator precedence are two different things.

Your best guess is correct. All the multiplicative operators `*` `/` `%` have the same precedence, and bind left-to-right. The additive operator `-` has lower precedence. The unary `!` operator binds more tightly than the multiplicative or additive operators.  And the assignment operator `=` has very low precedence (but still higher than the comma operator).

So this:

```
z = !x + y * z / 4 % 2 - 1
```

is equivalent to this:

```
z = (!x) + (((y * z) / 4) % 2) - 1
```

But the operands may legally be evaluated in any order (except for certain operators like `&&`, `||`, `,`, which impose left-to-right evaluation). If the operands are simple variables, this probably doesn't matter, but in something like:

```
z = func(x) * func(y);
```

the two function calls may occur in either order.

Comment: Shouldn't it be z = ((!x) + (((y * z) / 4) % 2)) - 1     as + and - are left associative ? @Keith Thomson

Comment: @AtulGangwar: It works either way. I could also have written `z = (((!x) + (((y * z) / 4) % 2)) - 1)` to make the precedence of the assignment operator more explicit.

Comment: Yes. But technically '+' will be done before '-'  in this example right ? I needed to know this for a different example. For example what if the addition overflows ?

Comment: @AtulGangwar: Yes, in general, `a + b - c` is equivalent to `(a + b) - c`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't understand it, rewrite your expression

```
z = !x + y * z / 4 % 2 - 1

notx = !x;         /* you can move this line 1, 2, or 3 lines down */
tmp1 = y * z;
tmp2 = tmp1 / 4;
tmp3 = tmp2 % 2;
tmp4 = notx + tmp3;
tmp5 = tmp4 - 1;
```

Comment: I don't know if it’s just me, but all the `tmp`s just seem more confusing :P

Comment: But rewriting it requires the same knowledge as parenthesising it does!

Comment: Not really because usually you are not starting with a fully fledged C equation but either written math or a math concept of what you want to calculate in your mind; and you should really understand what you *want* before starting to code. Writing that down in simple C terms as in this answer makes it more likely that the intended meaning is retained. Likewise, use parentheses if you are not 100% sure - your successors will thank you.